# Ошибка в моём коде jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, браузер

```
<style>
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    function toggledescription(el) {
    var selector = el.getAttribute('descSelector');
    $(selector).toggleClass('hidden');
}   
    $('.img-2').css('position','absolute').css('bottom','20px').css('left','10px')
```

});

```
</script>

<img src="file:///C:/Users/naza1/Desktop/jQuery/images/2.png" descSelector="#somedesc" onclick="toggledescription(this)" />
<div id="somedesc" class="hidden">Image description</div>
```

Не могу понять,в чём ошибка, в браузере выделяет 
welcome.html:57 
Uncaught ReferenceError: toggledescription is not defined
    at HTMLImageElement.onclick (welcome.html:57)
Как это исправить?
Хочу сделать так,чтобы при нажатии на картинку высвечивался блок с информацией

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `toggledescription` не видна снаружи обработчика `$(document).ready(function(){`, в котором она объявлена.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function toggledescription(el) {
    var selector = el.getAttribute('descSelector');
    $(selector).toggleClass('hidden');
  }
  
  $("img[descSelector]").click(function(e) {
    toggledescription(this);
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
#somedesc {
  font-size:x-large;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="file:///C:/Users/naza1/Desktop/jQuery/images/2.png" descSelector="#somedesc" />
<div id="somedesc" class="hidden">Image description</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как сделать это текст больше и по центру?Просто он у меня какой-то маленький

Comment: @ХаххирЗачир стилями - см. в ответе

Comment: Спасибо, помогли